# Angular getter/setter with an argument that can be undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

How can you write a ng-model setter method that can accept undefined? For example when the user empties an input with the type set to date, angular sends `undefined` as the new value which means `angular.isDefined()` no longer can be used to determine if the method was called as a getter or setter. This is the example of getter/setter method given in the documentation:

```
$scope.user = {
  name: function (newName) {
    if (angular.isDefined(newName)) {
      _name = newName;
    }
    return _name;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using javascript's native `arguments` property makes this easy to resolve and I will suggest an edit to angular's documentation. Here is an example:

```
$scope.user = {
  name: function (newName) {
    if (arguments.length > 0) {
      _name = newName;
    }
    return _name;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The built-in object `arguments` included with all JavaScript function calls is just an array of the arguments. ([w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_parameters.asp)) Comparing an array by name against zero with `arguments > 0` evaluates to `false`. You need to compare against the array length.

```
$scope.user = {
    name: function (newName) {
        if (arguments.length > 0) {
            _name = newName;
        }
        return _name;
    }
};
```